# QWebEnginePage: disable links

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm porting a software from PyQt4 to PyQt5.

With PyQt4, I used to use a QWebView to render html strings (so, no web browsing, just some rendering). Therefore, I could disable "browsing" with this setting:

```
self.page().setLinkDelegationPolicy(QtWebKit.QWebPage.DelegateAllLinks)
```

Where `self` was my QWebView.

However, I'm now forced to `QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView`. It's not that bad, but I can't use the previous setting anymore.

`QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEnginePage` doesn't have the DelegateAllLinks setting.

I would like to disable all the links in the view, so the user won't be able to click one of them and mess up with my software.

Do you have any idea ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly: are you absolutely sure you need to use a full web browser just to render some static html? The [QTextBrowser](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextbrowser.html) class only supports a limited subset of HTML4, but if your html is simple it would be a much better choice than a super-heavyweight class like `QWebEngineView`.

Anyway, if you really must use the `QWebEngineView` class, the only alternative to `setLinkDelegationPolicy` is to reimplement the [acceptNavigationRequest](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebenginepage.html#acceptNavigationRequest) method of the web-page:

```
class WebEnginePage(QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEnginePage):
    def acceptNavigationRequest(self, url, navtype, mainframe):
        return False
```

Comment: Good suggestion, my html is pretty simple (bold, italic, sub/supscript). But I also need to render one image (from a local file) at the end of the text. And I also need a zoom feature (Ctrl+mouse). Do you think QTextBrowser would fit ?

Comment: @Rififi. It sounds like it might. The [Supported HTML Subset](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/richtext-html-subset.html) includes image tags, and there's `zoomIn` and `zoomOut` slots. The zoom only works for text, though (i.e. not images).

Comment: Arf, I also need the zoom feature on the image. Plus everything is already there, I will stick with QWebEngineView. Subclassing WebEnginePage worked like a charm, thanks !